# Spark - Divide int with column?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to divide a constant with a column. I know I can do

```
df.col("col1").divide(90)
```

but how can I do `(90).divide(df.col("col1"))` (obviously this is incorrect).
Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `o.a.s.sql.functions.lit`:

```
lit(90).divide(df.col("col1"))
```

or `o.a.s.sql.functions.expr`:

```
expr("90 / col1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this can be used as well

```
lit(90)/col("col1")
```